# A precise formula for the summation of an inner product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information

We have $2$ strings $|v\rangle$ and $\langle u|$,

String $-1$ :

$$|v\rangle=|e_{1}\rangle^{np}|e_{2}\rangle^{n(1-p)}$$

> where :
>
> $e_{1}$ occurs $np$ times
>
> $e_{2}$ occurs $n(1-p)$ times

String $-2$ :

$$\langle u|=\langle f_{1}|^{nq}\langle f_{2}|^{n(1-q)}$$

> where :
>
> $f_{1}$ occurs $nq$ times
>
> $f_{2}$ occurs $n(1-q)$ times

Note that here  $e_{1}, e_{2}$ form an orthonormal basis and so do $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$.

$p$ and $q$ are probabilities therefore $np,nq$ etc can be a decimal, in this case they would be rounded off to the nearest whole number. Let $|v_{s}\rangle$ be a permuted version of of $|v \rangle$ and let $\langle u_{s'}|$ be a permuted form of $\langle u|$

Now an inner product is formed $\langle u_{s'}|v_{s}\rangle$. Basically every permutation of $|v\rangle$ is combined with every other permutation of $\langle u|$ to form the inner product.

I want to be able to find a formula for $\Sigma_{s,s^{'}}\langle u_{s'}|v_{s}\rangle$ where the summation is on the number of permutations of $|v\rangle$ and $\langle u|$.

How can we find this in general? The summation should be a function of $p$ , $q$ and $n$. Basically in $\Sigma_{s,s^{'}}\langle u_{s'}|v_{s}\rangle$ how many $\langle e_{1}|f_{1}\rangle$, $\langle e_{2}|f_{1}\rangle$, $\langle e_{2}|f_{2}\rangle$, $\langle e_{1}|f_{2}\rangle$ are there? Their numbers should be a function of $n$ , $p$ , $q$

I could find this in code for a given $n$ , $p$ and $q$. But I need a general formula for this mathematically for any $n$ , $p$ and $q$. What would be the formula in case of $n$ going to infinity?

Comment: Hi, I think one could get a reasonably compact answer using representations of the permutation group. But perhaps this question would be better answered by the people on [math.se].

Comment: Perhaps! Thanks, will ask the folks in the math stack exchange

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3695125/11127